# De-Duplicate RSS Feeds

Tags: rss, web, newsreader

Does anyone know of a web service/desktop RSS Reader application that has some built-in smarts to de-duplicate posts across blogs?

Its gets just downright annoying when you have 7-8 RSS Feeds on a similar subject, and have to go through 7-8 posts about the same topic 'Eg: Business X has released patches'.

Recently http://www.feedafever.com/ was released. I really like the way it works, but dont really want to have to set up a SQL Server to run it.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about any specific application that will do this for you but you can use [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to do this for you. You can build up your own pipe that filters out duplicated items in a particular RSS feed, and then point your preferred RSS reader at the newly generated feed from Yahoo.

I have been using this technique for quite a while you amalgamate all the separate BBC news feeds. You can view and clone the pipe I created [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=qAlsjBUh3BG8e_qRdbq02Q). Or the much simpler one that just does the de-duplication [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=ni8EMCy92xG0TX_zlfXiAA).